# Justifying summation factoring

Tags: combinatorics, summation

In my notes I have this formula ($\mu_P,\mu_Q$ here is the Möbius function and $[x,x'],[y,y']$ are intervals in locally finite Posets P,Q).

$$\sum_{x\leq u \leq x',y\leq v \leq y'}\mu_P(u,x)\mu_Q(y,v)=\left(\sum_{x\leq u \leq x'}\mu_P(x,u)\right)\left(\sum_{y\leq v \leq y'}\mu_Q(y,v)\right)$$

It's glossed over like something completely obvious, but I can't quite see it. I guess LHS is somethink like adding ''squares'' (''areas'') and the RHS is like adding's lengths first, then multiplying them to get the same ''area'' but I can't justify it rigorously.

Comment: Are you sure about the sum in the RHS?  $\sum_{u\in[x,x'],v\in[y,y']}\mu(u,x')=\#[y,y']\sum_{u\in[x,x']}\mu(u,x')$ and similar for the other factor.

Comment: Yes, I just confirmed, I am missing subscrips on the mobuis functions (they're not actually the same) but I think that that's probably obvious.

Comment: Nevermind, there was a mistake. Its updated (x' was transposed with u and should have been x)

Comment: Was also a little sloppy with summation ranges but I dont think anything changes.

Comment: @Muselive: Each side of the identity is simply the sum of all possible products of the form $$\mu_P(u,x)\mu_Q(y,v)$$ with $x\le u\le x'$ and $y\le v\le y'$. It’s entirely analogous to the identity $$\sum_{k=1}^m\sum_{\ell=1}^na_kb_\ell=\left(\sum_{k=1}^ma_k\right)\left(\sum_{\ell=1}^nb_\ell\right)\,.$$

Comment: Yeah that's embarrassing, Here I am thinking its some specials property of $\mu$. I imagine this will be closed soon, but thanks for the assist

Comment: @Muselive: You’re welcome.